# How to fix "Content showing below Searchbar" in Flutter?

Tags: search, flutter, dart, searchbar

I wanted to show the result or content in Full Screen after clicking on Suggested List from the Search bar, not below the Search bar as shown in the provided Screenshot below...

Tried to follow up with the flutter boring show, but not able to understand how they achieve it .

Thanks in Advance !!!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'urls_index.dart';
import 'ContentPage.dart';

class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
var names = new urlsindexs();

@override
List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
return [
  IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
    onPressed: () {
      query = "";
    },
  ),
];
}

@override
Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {

return IconButton(
    icon: AnimatedIcon(
      icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
      progress: transitionAnimation,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      close(context, null);
    });
}

@override
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {

return ContentPage();
}

@override
Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement buildSuggestions
var abc = query.isEmpty
    ? names.websitename
    : names.websitename
        .where((p) => p.toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
        .toList();

return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          showResults(context);
        },
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
              text: abc[index].substring(0, query.length),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: abc[index].substring(query.length),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
  itemCount: abc.length,
);
}
}
```

Getting This : https://ibb.co/vYW4G3x
Wanted to achieve This : https://ibb.co/pzBpNPK  (without searchbar)

SOLVED !
What i changed...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'urls_index.dart';

class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
var names = new urlsindexs();

@override
List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
return [
  IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
    onPressed: () {
      query = "";
    },
  ),
];
}

@override
Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement buildLeading
return IconButton(
    icon: AnimatedIcon(
      icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
      progress: transitionAnimation,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      close(context, null);
    });
}

@override
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement buildResults
var abc = query.isEmpty
    ? names.websitename
    : names.websitename
        .where((p) => p.toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
        .toList();

return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          showResults(context);
        },
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
              text: abc[index].substring(0, query.length),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: abc[index].substring(query.length),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
  itemCount: abc.length,
);
}

@override
Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement buildSuggestions
var abc = query.isEmpty
    ? names.websitename
    : names.websitename
        .where((p) => p.toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
        .toList();

return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          // showResults(context);
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Store1");
        },
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
              text: abc[index].substring(0, query.length),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: abc[index].substring(query.length),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    itemCount: abc.length,
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just open a new route with your content page (I'm guessing its a webview)? That shouldn't have the search dialog on the top. I've never used search delegate, so there may be a method there too, but if not, try adding an `onclick` route push instead. That will most certainly give you what you want.

Comment: Hello @ishaan Thanks For The help ! I Figured out the Solution with the help of your Suggestion....